# How to add header to requests with interceptor? Ktor client

Tags: android, kotlin, ktor-client

I have ktor client interceptor and I want is request contains some header add another header but I don't know how to add header to request
My code is

```
  install(HttpSend) {
                intercept { call, _ ->
                    val request = call.request
                    if(request.headers["No-Authentication"] == null){
// add header
                        header = prefs.getString("UserToken", null) ?: ""
                    }
                    call
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I tried this and it worked well!

```
install(DefaultRequest) {
    if (!headers.contains("No-Authentication")) {
        header("Authorization", prefs.getString("UserToken", null) ?: "")
    }
}
```